# How to get push notification custom data from Firebase when app is terminated

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification

Currently, my app gets all the push notifications when in the background and terminated state (currently implementing local notification).
When I send custom data in the Firebase console, all the data is correctly passed to the app when it is run foreground and background. However, when the app is terminated, the push message comes but the data is not retrieved successfully(only null data).

Is there any way to solve this? I don't understand why the push comes but then data does not.
It would be really nice if you help out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you app startup from FCM message click when your app terminated, you need to custom this

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) { //do something })
```

Comment: does this code only work when the app is terminated? for debug, I want to see if this works but because I use my android device, I can't see the log. I am new to flutter so, 감사합니다!

Answer (score 0):

For FCM push you will get data when app was in killed stae and push notification come and user tap on notification then you will get data in launcher screen.

Comment: if the data is received in the launch screen, then is there any way to access it in another way? What if I want to store that data?

Comment: You can either store them locally or use sharedpreferences  and once that data used clear it for another new data.

Comment: I am really sorry but I am new to flutter so I don't know how I can store the data.. from where can I have access to that data?